# JQUERY Datatable filtering based on a column value in which the column contains HTML data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a Table in which am appying JQUERY Datatable plugin. Things works fine. But my first column of the table, each cells contains HTML data. Not just text alone.

[image]

Actually the column content markup is as follows. Its actually a column which shows rating for each users. When a rating is applied it looks like this

[image]

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
<input type="checkbox" class="row-check"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg star-rating" data-original-title="" title="">
<i class="fa fa-star-o graystar  fa-stack-2x"></i><strong class="fa-stack-1x inside-text">
</strong></span>
</td>
```

So in the markup as you can see there is a Strong tag with a class **inside-text** to which the rating is given and it will show inside the **star**. So Iam trying to make a filter to search or filter the table in which the first column content alone to be searched to find a specific rating based on the HTML content of that cell in first column.

The way I tried is

```
function applyRatingFilter() {
    var table = $('#tbl_main').DataTable();
    var rating = $('.popover').find('.rating').val();
    table.columns(0).search(rating).draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-search` attribute on `<td>` element to specify value used for filtering. Below is an excerpt from the manual:

> DataTables will automatically detect the following attributes on HTML cells:
>
> `data-sort` or `data-order` - for ordering data
>
> `data-filter` or `data-search` - for search data

**Example:**

```
<tr>    
    <td data-search="3">
       <input type="checkbox" class="row-check"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg star-rating" data-original-title="" title="">
       <i class="fa fa-star-o graystar  fa-stack-2x"></i><strong class="fa-stack-1x inside-text">
       3
       </strong></span>
    </td>    
    <td>System Architect</td>    
    <td>Edinburgh</td>    
    <td>61</td>    
    <td>Mon 25th Apr 11</td>    
    <td>$3,120/m</td>
</tr>
```

See [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data#HTML-5) or [example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) for more information on `data-` attributes.

Alternatively you can use [render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) method, detect filtering event (`type == 'filter'`) and return desired value instead. Code `$('#example').DataTable().cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$()` returns `<td>` jQuery element.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         if(type === 'filter'){
            return $('#example').DataTable().cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$().find('.inside-text').text();
         } else {
            return data;
         }
      }
   }]
});
```